# How to use cocoapods with multiple xcode projects in different directories

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have 3 different xcode projects for 3 different apps in different directories. For example:

```
          myApps
            |
----------------------------------------------
|                        |                 |
app1                   app2              app3
|                        |                 |
app1.xcodeproj  app2.xcodeproj    app3.xcodeproj
```

I already ran cocoapods in the app1 directory. Now I'd like to run it in the other two directories. Should I create a new Podfile in each of the other 2 directories and rerun pod init and pod install. Or should I move the Podfile from one app1 directory to the app2 directory, modify it with the target for app2 and rerun pod init and pod install? What is the proper and best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up copying my Podfile to each individual directory and modifying them as appropriate. Then I ran pod install on each directory. This worked well.